# Android: map device rotation to 3d scene object rotation

Tags: matrix, vector, rotation, android-sensors, quaternions

My goal is to use a smartphone to rotate an object in a 3d scene. Basically I want to map the rotation of the phone to the one of the 3d object. The 3d software enables to rotate an object using a rotation function that takes as parameters an axis and an angle (a rotation vector). Another option is to use a rotation matrix.

I tried to use android rotation vector sensor to get a quaternion and isolate theta (rotation angle), x,y and z(coordinates of the rotation axis) out of it. It works but the problem is that this sensor gives the quaternion that corresponds to the rotation from current phone position to a reference (based on magnetic north). What I need is to get the quaternion that enables to get from position at t0 to position at t1. What I got is how to get from position at t0 to reference and from position at t1 to reference.

Is it possible then to compute the quaternion from position 1 to position 2 using the reference ? Maybe my strategy is not good so don't hesitate to propose "the right way to do it".
Thanks in advance

EDIT

Hi again everyone, I tried to use two successive quaternions. Lets call them q1 and q2. At t=1 I'm at position1 and q1 represents a rotation to earth reference. At t=2, I'm at position2 and q2 represents a rotation to the same earth reference. I computed the combination of -q2*q1. It works but the problem is that the rotations are mapped to the device coordinate system. What I need is to map to the real world coordinates system. Anyone knows how to do this ? Thanks

EDIT

I think I can name what I need: how to get the the rotation of my android device in the form of a unit quaternion in real world space ? Thus my implementation will work on this. Thanks in advance guys !

EDIT

Ok, I kinda worked it out. I used the rotation matrix R, obtained from getRotationMatrix(), and multiplied my quaternions with the inverted R matrix. The result is what I want, when I rotate the device in space, the 3d object in the software mimics the rotation exactly. There is one problem still though, this only works when I'm facing one specific direction with my device, I guess it is the reference (x to east, y to magnetic north and z up). I am currently triying to solve this out. If anyone can give me insight he's welcome!

EDIT

Hey me again world ! (empty desolated lonely world...) I think I got it. I want to use an initial quaternion value let's call it rotation toward initial position of the phone Qi.Once i Get it I combine it to the current quaternion value and get the rotation matrix out of it to map to the real world inital position ( and not north).

My only problem is that I don't know how to get only this first value as constant I tried :

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (this.initialQ==null) {
        this.initialQ=event.values; 
        this.conjInitQ=conjugate(this.initialQ);
    }
  Log.v(TAG,String.valueOf(initialQ[0])+String.valueOf(initialQ[1])+String.valueOf(initialQ[2])+String.valueOf(initialQ[3]));
```

However the value printed by the log is constantly changing, can anybody explain to my why ? Thanks in advance